# Iterate through a container of types different based on template parameter to call same method

Tags: c++

(I'm restricted to C++14 for now but if C++17 or 20 can allow this, please do say)

I have a class/struct containing different types:

```
struct Aggregation
{
    Something<P> _p;
    Something<S> _s;
    Something<T> _t;
    // There's a lot more
};
```

Although each type is simply a different templated parameter of `Something`:

```
template<class T>
struct Something
{
    std::string export(){return "some stuff";}
};
```

I want to store these types in a container.

This is because I need to loop across all objects and call the same method:

```
std::string str;
for(auto& obj : some_container)
{
    str += obj.export() + ",";
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you considered type erasure/static polymorphism?

Comment: @rturrado I'm not sure how static poly. would allow me to aggregate the objects in a container though?

Comment: Yes, it should. Have a look at this video from Sean Parent's (it's only 25 minutes long). They use there a `document_t = vector<object_t>`; in your case, `object_t` would be a `Something<T>`. Or use runtime polymorphism as Drew Dorman suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this possible?

Yes!  Create a common base, with the common functionality.

```
struct SomethingBase
{
    virtual std::string export() = 0;
};
```

Every instantiation of `Something` can inherit from that common base.

```
template<class T>
struct Something : SomethingBase
{
    std::string export() override {return "some stuff";}
};
```

You may now create any container of pointers to the common base.  They may refer to any instantiation of `Something`.

```
// If the container owns the objects:
std::vector< std::unique_ptr<SomethingBase> > some_container;

// or

// If the objects are owned elsewhere:
std::vector< SomethingBase* > some_container;
```

Your proposed code (adjusted for pointers) will now work.

```
std::string str;
for(auto const& obj : some_container)
{
    str += obj->export() + ",";
}
```

Comment: Ah nice. Btw i think you forgot to change `CommonBase` in the unique_ptr

Comment: The way I read the OP's question, there are probably multiple `Aggregation` objects and the OP wants to loop over a given member of those objects. Or maybe just all members of one `Aggregation` object. In either case, `unique_ptr` would be the wrong thing to use here, but your suggestion to use a common base class would still apply, eg: `std::vector<SomethingBase*> some_container; some_container.push_back(&obj1._p); some_container.push_back(&obj2._p); ...` Or: `some_container.push_back(&obj._p); some_container.push_back(&obj._s); ...`

Comment: @RemyLebeau that's very possible.  I wonder if I can adjust this answer without going down a rabbit-hole regarding "ownership".  Or possibly your comment does that job.

Comment: @DrewDormann hard to say for sure, since the OP didn't explain the use case for the container in question.

Comment: @RemyLebeau One Aggregation object, multiple members.